# Error while using has_secure_password. cannot load such file -- 2.0/bcrypt_ext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt-ruby, bundle-install

I'm new to Ruby on Rails ans so I'm following the Tutorial Agile Web Development with Rails 4. But on the User Authentification I'm getting an Error which I just can't solve... 
I've made a Form so the Users can log in and for that I'm using has_secure_password at the file user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

but when I run the Server i get the error:

```
cannot load such file -- 2.0/bcrypt_ext
```

heres the Application Trace

```
app/models/user.rb:2:in `<class:User>'
app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `index'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
   bcrypt
   bcrypt_ext
   2.0/bcrypt_ext
```

I have includet  gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0' in the gemfile but it still don't works.

I've read in similar Questions that it has something to do with "Bundle install" but i can't solve the problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely,

```
gem install bcrypt-ruby
```

this will make `has_secure_password` work. Also remember to restart the rails server after to see the change.

Comment: Restarting the rails server solved it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can only imagine what platform are you using, but I assume *nix derivative.
Editing your `Gemfile` is not enough - `bundle install` command will do the job for you.
You'll need native compilation toolchain installed also, because `bcrypt_ruby` is building some native extensions during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using **RVM** if so you should install bcrypt gem for the `global gemset`:

```
rvm gemset use global
gem install bcrypt
rvm gemset use whatever_gemset_you_use_previously
```

(I use `bcrypt` instead of `bcrypt-ruby` because of the deprecation message for the latter)